# Mensagem para o usuário em Label com Jquery

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou fazendo validação do e-mail do usuário cadastrado, e quero exibir a mensagem pra ele caso o email já exista, então fiz assim:

```
    //validação de email
    $(function validateEmail() {
        $('#Email').change(function () {
            var url = '@Url.Action("ValidateEmail", "Ajax")';//url do controller que passará a informação
            var email = $('#Email').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: url,
                data: { email: email },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#MensagemEmail').append("Email Já Cadastrado");
                    $('#Email').focus();
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    $('#MensagemEmail').append("Email Disponível");
                }
            });
        });
    });//Fim da validação de email
```

o meu problema é que quando o usuário insere 2 emails que já tenha, a mensagem é duplicada como mostrado na imagem abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

minha dúvida é como faço para limpar o valor antes de inserir outro? pois eu tentei utilizar `$('#MensagemEmail').val('');` mas não rolou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) é somente para entrada de dados. No seu caso, visto que é um *label* existem várias formas, como [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) ou [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/):

```
$('#MensagemEmail').html('');
$('#MensagemEmail').text('');
```

Existe a função [empty()](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation/empty) também, que além de limpar os elementos também limpa os textos.

Comment: Valeu @lucascosta

Answer (score 0):

Olá, ja considerou usar o plugin Jquery validate? Esse trabalho fica bem mais simples com ele.

Segue um exemplo:

```
    $("#validaEmail").validate({
            rules: { 
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true,
                    remote: {
                        url: "<c:url value='/'/>login/email",
                        type: "get",
                        data: {
                            email: function() {
                                return $("#email").val();
                            }
                        }
                    }   
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: {
                    required: "Email é obrigatório",
                    remote: "Já existe uma conta associada a este email"
                }
            },
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                form.submit();
            }
        });
```

Usando o remote você passa a url que vai verificar se o email ja existe. Seu método só tem que retornar um true or false e a mensagem definida vai ser exibida.